# Mutually-referencing fields in window functions

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I have a table that contains a list of (year,points) and an initial number of points (100 in this example). I want to list each year with the (running) amount of points consumed:

```
create table test (
    year int
    ,points int
)

INSERT INTO test
SELECT generate_series(2000,2004),generate_series(10,50,10);
```

The result should look like this:

| year | points | available | consumed | remaining |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 10 | 100 | 10 | 90 |
| 2001 | 20 | 90 | 20 | 70 |
| 2002 | 30 | 70 | 30 | 40 |
| 2003 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 0 |
| 2004 | 50 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

The **available** column is just `COALESCE( LAG(remaining) OVER (ORDER BY year) ,100)`,
**consumed** is calculated with something like `LEAST(points,available)` and **remaining** is `available-consumed`.

So my query could look like this but of course it is not valid because every field depends on another one:

```
WITH config AS (
    SELECT 100 AS initial
)
select year, points
    ,available
    ,consumed
    ,remaining
FROM test
CROSS JOIN config
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT LEAST(points,available) AS consumed
) y
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT available-consumed AS remaining
) z
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT COALESCE( LAG(remaining) OVER w ,initial) AS available
    WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY year)
) x
```

What is the proper way of writing such constructs ? Should I use `SUM() OVER ()` to calculate some kind of running total?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute:

- "*available*" field, subtracting 100 from a running sum, implemented using the `SUM` window function with ordering on the "*points*" field and frame specification hitting all preceding rows till current one (not included). The `COALESCE` function will take care of the difference at first row.
- "*remaining*" field, equal to `available - points`. Since this value can become negative, you can use the `GREATEST` function to cap it to 0.
- "*consumed*" field, equal to `available - remaining`

```
WITH added_available AS (
    SELECT *,
           100 - COALESCE(SUM("points") OVER(ORDER BY "points" ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 0) AS available
    FROM test
), added_remaining AS (
    SELECT *,
           GREATEST(available - points, 0) AS remaining
    FROM added_available
)
SELECT year_,
       points,
       available,
       available - remaining AS consumed,
       remaining
FROM added_remaining
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xtjNBuRWDEkRh327gfcdfX/0).

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I have sorted on "years" because it makes more sense but the ROWS BETWEEN... and CTE calculation *before* was what I was missing. Special points for the GREATEST tip.